# Emtpy form project halt with access violation

Tags: c#

I am really new to C#, and I want to write a simple form program.

I've created a new .NET **Core** Form App from scratch, do nothing, just `Run`.

The form appears and suddenly die. A popup appears and get windows error message: RChat has stopped, windows will close and tell me when found a solution to my problem, etc... (not english message, my windows is hungarian). Can anybody tell my why is it happens?

**EDIT 1: If I am running the exe, I've got no errors, only if I run it from Visual Studio.**

**EDIT 2:** checking the Event Viewer and I see this (translated from hungarian to you):

> `The module what cause the error: ntdll.dll, version: 10.0.14393.3241,
>   timestamp: 0x5d786bef Exception Code: 0xc0000005 Error position:
>   0x0000000000065e59`

**EDIT 3: EDIT 1 is not true. It starts without error, but on any action I've got the same error.**

I did not write anything into the code:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace RChatClient
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    }
}
```

In the `Output` window I've got this:

> ```
> 'RChatClient.exe' (CoreCLR: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.0.0\System.Private.CoreLib.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
> 'RChatClient.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\R-Chat\RChatClient\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.0\RChatClient.dll'. Symbols loaded.
> 'RChatClient.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.0.0\System.Runtime.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
> 'RChatClient.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App\3.0.0\System.Windows.Forms.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
> 'RChatClient.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.0.0\System.ComponentModel.Primitives.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
> 'RChatClient.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.0.0\System.Drawing.Primitives.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
> 'RChatClient.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.0.0\System.Collections.Specialized.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
> 'RChatClient.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.0.0\System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
> 'RChatClient.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App\3.0.0\System.Drawing.Common.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
> 'RChatClient.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.0.0\System.Threading.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
> 'RChatClient.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.0.0\System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
> 'RChatClient.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.0.0\System.Collections.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
> 'RChatClient.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.0.0\System.Runtime.Extensions.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
> 'RChatClient.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.0.0\System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
> 'RChatClient.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.0.0\Microsoft.Win32.Primitives.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
> 'RChatClient.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.0.0\System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
> 'RChatClient.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.0.0\System.Threading.Thread.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
> 'RChatClient.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App\3.0.0\Accessibility.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
> 'RChatClient.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.0.0\System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
> 'RChatClient.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.0.0\System.ComponentModel.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
> 'RChatClient.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App\3.0.0\Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
> 'RChatClient.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.0.0\System.Buffers.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
> 'RChatClient.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.0.0\System.Collections.NonGeneric.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
> The program '[3120] RChatClient.exe' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.
> ```

I've also tried to create a .NET **Framework** Form App, and when run get this:

> ```
> 'RChatClient.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
> 'RChatClient.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\R-Chat\RChatClient\RChatClient\bin\Debug\RChatClient.exe'. Symbols loaded.
> 'RChatClient.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: RChatClient.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
> 'RChatClient.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: RChatClient.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
> 'RChatClient.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: RChatClient.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
> 'RChatClient.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: RChatClient.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
> 'RChatClient.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: RChatClient.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
> 'RChatClient.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: RChatClient.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
> The program '[3284] RChatClient.exe' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.
> ```

Comment: Are you running in Release mode?

Comment: I will check, honestly, I do not know what is that, but sounds, it could be a good starting point, thanks. Currently I am updating the VS to the latest.

Comment: @KennethK. No, I am running in debug mode.

Answer (score 2):

Holy crap, it is unbelivible what happened. I've just totally purged and reinstall the whole Visual Studio, tried a lot of solution from other topics and forums, played with debug and other settings without success, you won't believe it what causes the problem.

After, I turned on the `Enable native code debugging` checkbox for project properties at debugging section, I've got an exception at this line:

```
Application.Run(new LoginForm());
```

> Exception thrown at 0x00007FF819B0F5BD (cmdvrt64.dll) in
>   RChatClient.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location
>   0x0000000000000008.

I've searched for this dll, and it is a Comodo Internet Security related thing.

I've turned off the `Auto Containment` and everything is working fine.

Create a new Ignore rule in Comodo like this: https://help.comodo.com/topic-399-1-790-10323-.html